# How to get all the details of a tensorflow keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I was wondering how do you see all the details associated with a keras model. model.summary comment evidently doesn't give us all the details beyond output shapes and the number of optimizable parameters. How do you get the information about regularizer values and dropout layers etc.
I am using tensorflow version 2.4.1

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `model.get_config()` function to view all the model parameters.  The printout is messy, but you will find all the details for your different layers.

Answer (score 0):

you could simply used `model.summary()` to print number of parameters of the network along with layers. you can use `keras.utils.plot_model(model_name, "file_name")` to plot the graph of your model.

To examine your model, you can use tensorboard utilities like `.add_graph()` method.